# Not able to send my Google Forms anymore because of sections

Tags: google-forms

I was able to send an answer of a Google Form yesterday. I modified a bit the form, adding more questions and making some of them compulsory and I'm no more able to send the answers with the blue button.

Here is the form :

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScfzfXpSssJ_a-OTyUxqjs-vGBuCbKGnwbExlmorMUv5m03uw/viewform

Can you help me fixing that issue ?

I reported it to Google with the bottom button.

I merged every sections and I now can sand my answers but I would have preferred to have them by sections.

Comment: Did your form includes checkboxes / dropdowns? If so, are any of them set to go a section based on answer?

Comment: @Rubén I included multiple choices questions and question to answer on a linear scale. I don't understand what is "setting to go a section based on answer"

Comment: I posted and answer more than one month ago. Did it help you?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

If the form has required questions, that questions should always be shown to the respondent, otherwise the form response can't be submitted.

## Tips

- Check if the form has questions set as required, if so:

  - Turn off the required setting, or
  - Move the question to a sections that always will be shown.

Also you could:

- Check if any of the form checkbox / dropdown questions are set to "Go to section based on answer"
- Check if any section is set to go to a specific section instead of the next section

## References

- [Show questions based on answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en)